# Passing CLGeocoder city name to new class UILabel

Tags: objective-c

I´m currently trying to pass the city name retrieved by CLGeocoder successfully to a UILabel of another class. First the CLGecoder-class

FindLocation.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cityName;
```

FindLocation.m - inside method (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations   
{
if (self.isFirstUpdate) {
    self.isFirstUpdate = NO;
    return;
}

CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

if (location.horizontalAccuracy > 0) {
    self.currentLocation = location;}

CLGeocoder *fgeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

// Reverse Geocode a CLLocation to a CLPlacemark
[fgeo reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError 
*error){
    NSLog(@"%@", location);

               // Make sure the geocoder did not produce an error
               // before continuing
               if(!error){
                   // Iterate through all of the placemarks returned
                   // and output them to the console

                   for(CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks){
                       NSLog(@"%@",[placemark description]);
                       self.cityName = [placemark locality];
                       NSLog(@"city is %@",cityName); }

                   [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
                   [self.delegate findLocationDidGeocodeCityName:self.cityName];
               } else {
                   // Our geocoder had an error, output a message
                   // to the console
                   NSLog(@"There was a reverse geocoding error\n%@",
                         [error localizedDescription]);
```

Further in my FirstViewController it looks like this:

```
 FindLocation *cityname = [[FindLocation alloc] init];
     [cityname cityName];
     [self.cityLabel setText:(cityname.cityName)];
     NSLog(@"CityName is...%@", cityname.cityName); //Log shows CityName is...(null)
```

I don´t know whats wrong here. Since the city is found there must be something wrong with the latter part of code, but I don´t know what. Is the passing of NSString - cityName implemented wrong?

Comment: I would set a breakpoint at the beginning of your locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method and step through line by line. I wonder if it's updating only once, and so returning after setting `self.isFirstUpdate=NO`. Or maybe just comment out the `return;` statement for now and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah, it´s getting called now, but still no luck with the label printing the city

Comment: Might be a silly question, but are you sure cityLabel is wired up in Interface Builder?

Comment: If you want to post the code somewhere, I'll be happy to take a quick look and see if I can spot the issue

Comment: http://julespierre.se/FILES/WXManager.m
http://julespierre.se/FILES/WXController.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the geocode process is not instantaneous. You are instantiating `FindLocation` and then immediately trying to access `cityName`. However, even assuming that your init method triggers the location update, the geocoder will take a little bit of time to go to the server and get a response. Additionally, the location manager won't return a location immediately, and since it looks like that is what kicks off the geocoder, you have to wait a little bit longer for that as well.

One solution here would be to implement a delegate protocol on FindLocation so that it can notify FirstViewController when the geocoding has completed. Something like this:

FindLocation.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class FindLocation;
@protocol FindLocationDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)findLocationDidGeocodeCityName:(NSString *)cityName;
@end

@interface FindLocation : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<FindLocationDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

and then in your CLGeocoder completionHandler after retrieving cityName:

```
[self.delegate findLocationDidGeocodeCityName:self.cityName];
```

Now, in FirstviewController.h, indicate that you conform to the FindLocationDelegate protocol:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <FindLocationDelegate>
```

In your FirstViewController.m, set the delegate like so:

```
FindLocation *cityName = [[FindLocation alloc] init];
cityName.delegate = self;
```

and then also in FirstViewController, implement the delegate method:

```
#pragma mark - FindLocation Delegate

- (void)findLocationDidGeocodeCityName:(NSString *)cityName
{
     [self.cityLabel setText:cityName];
}
```

There are other ways to do this as well, but the key is you have to wait until the completionHandler runs, and then notify any other interested objects about what got returned.

Comment: The part where I set the delegate calls the error: assigning to id from incompatible type strong

Comment: Where are you calling that code? Can you post the method for me to look at?

Comment: I´m calling that code in viewDidLoad. What method do you mean?

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot an identifier in my code. In your FirstViewController.h, you need to add `<FindLocationDelegate>`. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Not it runs without errors, however the Label wont´s show the cityname still. Do I have to instantiate the method findLocationDidGeocodeCityName:(NSString *)cityName somewhere?

Comment: In FirstViewController.m, in the -findLocationDidGeocodeCityName: method, put this: `NSLog(@"%@", cityName);` and see if you get (null)

Comment: Tried but it doesnt get called

Comment: In that case I suspect your completionHandler isn't getting called. Can you put an NSLog() statement in there or set a breakpoint to see if that's ever getting called in FindLocation?

Comment: If you want to post that code I can take a look at it, but it might be better making that a separate question since it's a different issue